# ASP.NET - Possible to create tag with onclick event on button?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a page with a TextArea which allow you to send one message. But in my case I would like to send several messages.

I was thinking to have a button which create a new TextArea as much as I want but I'm not founding the solution.

`@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.MessageToSend, new { style = "width: 1200px; height: 600px;" })`
Above this is the textbox I want to create/duplicate by clicking on button.

-- I already can send messages, I just want to create other TextArea by clicking on the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to send multiple message, it is better to change the `MessageToSend` property data type from `string` to `List<string>`. Code like this:

```
public class MessageViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<string> MessageToSend { get; set; }
}
```

In the View Page, when the page load you could copy the initial `textarea` and use it as a template. Then, you could add a Font Awesome Plus Icon to show the Add button. In its click event, you could dynamically add the `textarea` element according the template. Code as below:

HomeController:

```
    public IActionResult SendMessage()
    {
        MessageViewModel model = new MessageViewModel() { MessageToSend = new List<string>() { "" }, Title="" };
        return View(model);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SendMessage(MessageViewModel message)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(message);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

SendMessage View Page:

```
@model MVCWebApplication.Models.MessageViewModel
 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="SendMessage">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="MessageToSend" class="control-label"></label> <i class="fa fa-plus" id="iconAdd" style="font-size:22px"></i>
                <div id="multiple">
                    @if (Model.MessageToSend.Count > 0)
                    {
                        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.MessageToSend.Count; i++)
                        {
                            @Html.TextAreaFor(c=>c.MessageToSend[i], new{ style = "width: 1200px; height: 60px;"})
                        }
                    }

                </div><span asp-validation-for="MessageToSend" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />    <input type="button" id="btnAjaxCreate" value="Ajax Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

At the end of the above page, add the following scripts:

```
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
    <script>
        $(function () {
            //get the first textarea, use it as a template.
            var existingtext = $("#multiple").html();
            //submit button click event
            $("#iconAdd").click(function () {
                //get the count of the textarea.
                var num = $("#multiple").find("textarea").length;
                //change the template id and name value.
                newtext = existingtext.replace("MessageToSend[0]", "MessageToSend[" + num + "]").replace("MessageToSend_0_", "MessageToSend_" + num + "_");
                //dynamically add the textarea element.
                var htmlcontent = $("#multiple").html() + newtext;
                $("#multiple").html(htmlcontent);
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Besides, you could also use `JQuery.Ajax` to send the data to the action method.

Add the following action method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AjaxSendMessage(MessageViewModel message)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Ok("success");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

and add the following scripts:

```
            //using Ajax to send the data to the action method.
            $("#btnAjaxCreate").click(function () {
                //create a object to store the entered data.
                var message = {};
                message.Title = $("#Title").val();
                var messgecontent = [];
                $("#multiple").find("textarea").each(function (index, item) {
                    messgecontent.push($(item).val());
                });
                message.MessageToSend = messgecontent;

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/AjaxSendMessage",
                    method: "Post",
                    data: message,
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert(response);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        console.log("error");
                    }
                })

            });
```

The result like this:

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, I integrated some parts into my code. But I don't understand how can I use a method which is in my Model. I wanted to call this method by clicking on the "Create" button for example. This is a send method already created

Comment: "But I don't understand how can I use a method which is in my Model." Do you mean you still want to use your model (the MessageToSend property is string type)? If that is the case, you can also refer the above code to dynamically add the textarea element, but when you submit the data to the action method, you might only get the first textarea value. So, in my sample, I suggest you change the `string` type to `List<string>`. And if using the first method (change the template name and id attribute), we could send the multiple message via the Model Binding method.

Comment: "I wanted to call this method by clicking on the "Create" button for example." In this scenario, you could change the plus icon to an `<input type='button'>` element, then attach the button click event.

Comment: I forgot to notify, it's working ty. I didn't use everything but most of the code you send  was useful

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can , first u need to  install jquery . Then , u need to have your code inside a div like :

```
 <div id="multiple">
     @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.MessageToSend, new { style = "width: 1200px; height: 600px;" 
      })
  </div
```

Then Create a button to add multiple desks like:-

```
   <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="adder()">Adder</button>
```

At,last write script

```
  <script>
       function adder()//This function is called when u click that button
        {
           var html='';
           html += '@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.MessageToSend, new { style = "width: 1200px; height: 600px;" })
          })';
          $("#multiple").append(html); //This will stack your html input inside that id as we have name multiple and given id
      
        }
    
      </script>
```

But, you need to manage your controller

Comment: I'm  adding a nugget package (Jquery). When it's installed, should I add something in the code?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: messageAdder is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick  I have this error when I clicked on the button

Comment: so , if the message is uncaught reference . That means onclick , is not able to find adder() function . so make sure your function name defined at onclick matches with the same name on script

Comment: this is weird, this is the same name :/